What next step would be best with my preferred math PhDs in mind?
I applied for PhDs this December. My undergrad is in computer science and my master’s which I have just finished is in theoretical computer science, both in Greece.
I was mostly aiming for a math PhD with a year or two of coursework. Instead, I have been accepted into the computer science department of Purdue and no other university thus far. Unfortunately, Purdue’s cs and math departments have no research I know and like right now- I would have to find something there.
Right now I can see two options.
A) Go to Purdue. Take courses from the math department (computer science course requirements are very lax) and apply to it in December. Apply to other math schools as well. I will also have to do work as a teaching assistant, so I will have no time for research.
B) Stay in Greece. Try to get a paper submitted with a professor here before December. Maybe take some math courses. Apply again.
What would strengthen my applications the most?
To give a idea of where I applied and how strong my application was, schools of first preference are Toronto (math), Warwick (math), UIUC (math), Chicago(CS), Waterloo (Combinatorics and optimization program), Georgia tech (Algorithms, combinatorics, optimization program), CMU ( Algorithms, combinatorics, optimization). I had publishable results from my master’s thesis but no paper.

I think you are mistaken about Purdue (West Lafayette campus)'s math "having no research". By various rankings, it's probably in the top 30 in the country. Certainly counts as an "R1" in the U.S. sense. I'd imagine that its CS dept is not far behind. How did you get these impressions?

@paulgarrett: You elided the "... I know and like right now". I think OP knows there's research, but not on topics they're interested in pursuing at this time.

@DanielR.Collins, ah, yeah, thanks for noting that. I think I somehow didn't parse that phrase correctly... sigh...

I have a PhD in math, and a master's in computer science. I got them at the same graduate university in the US. I agree with Paul's comment that Purdue is a very good research university and almost certainly has some research that you'd be interested in. I encourage you to look harder and don't be afraid to email professors and express interest in their research. That can also suggest to you if CS students ever work with a math advisor.
Regardless of which option you pick, it seems clear to me that between now and September you should write up your master's thesis as a paper (either conference proceeding or journal article). It will be MUCH harder for you to find time for that once you start the PhD program, so do it now!
Another thing you might think about is that it's much easier to get a job (in academia or outside academia) with a PhD in computer science than one in math. My master's advisor in computer science could easily have been a mathematician. My master's thesis was a proof in graph theory. Many advisors have broad interests and are ok with a strong and driven student charting his/her own path. So consider if anyone in Purdue's CS department could actually supervise you to do a more mathy thesis.
If you ascertain that no such person exists, then it might be wiser to wait and apply again next year. It would not look good to show up to the CS department and then immediately try to take math courses and work with a math advisor. Probably they will expect you to take CS courses in your first year, and there's probably a limit on how many courses you can take. I doubt you can take the first-year math qualifying exam courses and the CS courses at the same time. Transferring PhD programs is hard, and my instinct is that you might have a better shot getting cleanly accepted into a math department, rather than trying to switch over from CS, especially considering visa issues.
You also might want to talk to your letter of recommendation writers to be sure you're on the same page with them that you want to be in a math program. It's odd that you applied to so many CS programs if you are so sure you want to be in a math program. But, again, I think it's worthwhile to consider getting a PhD in CS with a mathy thesis.
